# WINE hh.exe (chm viewer) blocking external CHMs

Tags: wine

@wine-1.8

I have recently installed SP3 for Office 2007 from microsoft offcial site & all is well here but a problem is started that whenever .chm files (provided by nonMicrosoft developers) are opened this is displayed `"This program cannot display the webpage"`

I have tracked the problem & the solution is mentioned [here](https://ponderingdeveloper.com/2007/10/18/chm-error-this-program-cannot-display-the-webpage/)
But how do I rectify it in wine environment ..perhaps a registry editor hack will work

Answer (score 1):

problem is well documented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438634/opening-a-chm-file-produces-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled

I cannot resolve issue using regedit tricks ..neither by using application [HHReg](http://www.helpandmanual.com/products_hhreg.html)

@wine 1.8 & wine-staging 1.9.1

**Solution:**

1] `wine regedit` HKLM>Software>Microsoft>HTMLHelp ..delete 1.0 folder

2] `killall wineserver` ..ends wine session

3] Browse to Autocad2008 install dir, launch in using wine-staging 
 `/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine acad.exe`  ..updates wine settings to wine-staging session..check help chms will be working

4] exit AutoCAD & via terminal end wine-staging session via `killall wineserver`

5] run `wine winecfg` ..restores original wine settings ..all dlls remain intact but this hh.exe issue reolved